# Fallo de autenticación en GMail con laravel

Tags: laravel, gmail, mail

Acá dejo mi configuración utilizando laravel y una cuenta de Gsuite de google para utilzarla como Email, con mi dominio.

[image: Error]

Ahí dejo el error y mis configuraciones.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=administracion@mardeltrabaja.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=iyikhklfpfgehanp
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=administracion@mardeltrabaja.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Administrador
```

Y la configuración de la cuenta gsuite -

[image: Configuración de GSuite]

Ya me recorrí todas las guías de internet. Todos dicen que es de acceso a aplicaciones menos seguras, pero eso ya lo hice desde la cuenta administradora central de mi Gsuite que seria la mia personal de google y sigue sin dejarme loguear. También cambie la contraseña de aplicación 10 veces, probe reinciar el servidor y sigue diciendome ese error de autenticación.

Lo que puedo confirmar es que anteriormente funcionaba con otra cuenta. Asique hay algo que no estoy haciendo o me olvidé, agradezco cualquier ayuda gracias.

Comment: Prueba con `MAIL_PORT=587` y `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`

Comment: También eh probado de esa manera me sigue pasando lo mismo !